# Which is a general protocol used to communicate with all IM server?

Tags: java-me, protocols, instant-messaging

I m planing to develop IM client application using this application we can able to communicate with all IM server like google,yahoo,aim,jabber... while surfing net i have seen that lippurble is general library to communicate with all server but it has been developed by C.Is there is  lippurble j2me version available or some other library like libpurble for j2me mobile, because i m planing to create IM client for j2me and blackberry application.

Comment: libpurple is not a protocol, it's a library that implements a bunch of different protocols.  There is no one protocol that works with all IM services.

Comment: Hi wyzard thanks for ur information.Do you have any idea about,which protocol is used by which IM service.

Answer (score 2):

You can access Pidgin (libpurple) through the DBus. For Java access, you can use **[this library](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/)**.

Note that there is no single protocol for accessing all IM services: [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) is one implementation that comes the closest to matching your requirement (there are maybe others).